# from keyword not found where expected in case statement

Tags: sql, case

I have one query which i written below. I am getting error. I have already added double quotes. Still not working. Please suggest me.

```
SELECT  

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(BATCH_CREATION_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD') AS CREATION_DATE, 
SUM(DECODE(CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT)) AS CCOLLECTED,
SUM(DECODE(CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT)) - SUM(DECODE(CDR_PARSE_ERROR_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_PARSE_ERROR_COUNT))  
- SUM(DECODE(CDR_DISCARD_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_DISCARD_COUNT)) AS COLLECTED,
SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_CNR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CNR_COUNT)) + SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_CE_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CE_COUNT))   
+ SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_CR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CR_COUNT)) + SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_NCR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_NCR_COUNT))  AS ERRORED, 
SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_RNC_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_RNC_COUNT)) + SUM(DECODE(VALIDATION_RV_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_RV_COUNT)) AS PROCESSED 
"CDR_SOURCE_TYPE" =
CASE
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('SMSC') THEN DECODE(NETWORK_TYPE,'CDMA','SMSC_CDMA','HSPA','SMSC_HSPA') AS "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('P_GW') and BATCH_ID like '%_PGW_%' and BATCH_ID like '%_PGW_REPLAY_%' THEN 'PGW_REPLAY' AS "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('OCS_UDR','OCS_EDR','OCS_CDMA_EDR','OCS_UDR_RECOVER','MACH_UDR','AAA','PTT_CDMA','OCS_CDMA_UDR','MTX') THEN "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
--ELSE 'Excelent'
END

FROM  BATCH_SUMMARY

WHERE                 
BATCH_CREATION_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND BATCH_CREATION_TIME < (SYSDATE -1/24)
--and CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('OCS_UDR','OCS_EDR','OCS_CDMA_EDR','OCS_UDR_RECOVER','MACH_UDR','AAA','PTT_CDMA','OCS_CDMA_UDR','MTX')

GROUP BY 
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(BATCH_CREATION_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD'), CDR_SOURCE_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is `comma` missing.

Also you need to use the entire `case` statement in `group by` not the column name alone

```
SELECT
To_date(To_char(BATCH_CREATION_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD') AS CREATION_DATE,
Sum(Decode(CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT)) AS CCOLLECTED,
Sum(Decode(CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_ACTUAL_COUNT)) - Sum(Decode(CDR_PARSE_ERROR_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_PARSE_ERROR_COUNT))
- Sum(Decode(CDR_DISCARD_COUNT,NULL,0,CDR_DISCARD_COUNT)) AS COLLECTED,
Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_CNR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CNR_COUNT)) + Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_CE_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CE_COUNT))
+ Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_CR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_CR_COUNT)) + Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_NCR_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_NCR_COUNT))  AS ERRORED,
Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_RNC_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_RNC_COUNT)) + Sum(Decode(VALIDATION_RV_COUNT,NULL,0,VALIDATION_RV_COUNT)) AS PROCESSED ,

CASE
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('SMSC') THEN Decode(NETWORK_TYPE,'CDMA','SMSC_CDMA','HSPA','SMSC_HSPA')
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('P_GW') AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_%' AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_REPLAY_%' THEN 'PGW_REPLAY'
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('OCS_UDR','OCS_EDR','OCS_CDMA_EDR','OCS_UDR_RECOVER','MACH_UDR','AAA','PTT_CDMA','OCS_CDMA_UDR','MTX') THEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE
--ELSE 'Excelent'
END AS CDR_SOURCE_TYPE
FROM  BATCH_SUMMARY

WHERE
BATCH_CREATION_TIME BETWEEN To_date(To_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND To_date(To_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') ||' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND BATCH_CREATION_TIME < (SYSDATE -1/24)
--and CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('OCS_UDR','OCS_EDR','OCS_CDMA_EDR','OCS_UDR_RECOVER','MACH_UDR','AAA','PTT_CDMA','OCS_CDMA_UDR','MTX')

GROUP BY
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(BATCH_CREATION_TIME,'YYYY/MM/DD'),'YYYY/MM/DD'), 
CASE
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('SMSC') THEN Decode(NETWORK_TYPE,'CDMA','SMSC_CDMA','HSPA','SMSC_HSPA') AS "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('P_GW') AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_%' AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_REPLAY_%' THEN 'PGW_REPLAY' AS "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('OCS_UDR','OCS_EDR','OCS_CDMA_EDR','OCS_UDR_RECOVER','MACH_UDR','AAA','PTT_CDMA','OCS_CDMA_UDR','MTX') THEN "CDR_SOURCE_TYPE"
--ELSE 'Excelent'
END
```

Also make sure `Aliasname=column_name` format is supported in your database. In Sql server it will work. Else use

```
Column_name as Aliasname
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT CASE -- CDR_SOURCE_TYPE removed
         WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ( 'SMSC' ) THEN Decode(NETWORK_TYPE, 'CDMA', 'SMSC_CDMA',
                                                                      'HSPA', 'SMSC_HSPA')
         WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ( 'P_GW' )
              AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_%'
              AND BATCH_ID LIKE '%_PGW_REPLAY_%' THEN 'PGW_REPLAY'
       END
FROM   BATCH_SUMMARY
```

Comment: Added the comma... still same

Comment: @user2642751 - Did you change the alias name `"CDR_SOURCE_TYPE" =` to `as CDR_SOURCE_TYPE` format

Comment: @user2642751 - what is the error message you are getting

Comment: I am just trying to run the below simple query which is giving me now missing keyword...  select 
CASE CDR_SOURCE_TYPE
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('SMSC') THEN DECODE(NETWORK_TYPE,'CDMA','SMSC_CDMA','HSPA','SMSC_HSPA') 
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('P_GW') and BATCH_ID like '%_PGW_%' and BATCH_ID like '%_PGW_REPLAY_%' THEN 'PGW_REPLAY'
END
FROM  BATCH_SUMMARY

Comment: @user2642751 - You need to remove `CDR_SOURCE_TYPE ` present before `when` in `case statement`. check the update of my answer

Comment: yes, this is executing fine.. thanks for that.. when i am adding in my original query it is giving me "not a group by expression" because of CDR_SOURCE_TYPE

Comment: @user2642751 - problem is you need to use the entire case statement in group by not the column alone. Updated the complete query try now

Comment: Thank you so much... I really appreciated your help towards me... it worked fine for me now... thank you for understanding my situation as well..

Comment: @user2642751 - Gald it helped. You can mark this as answer by selecting the tick mark to the left of this answer so that it will be useful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Just focusing on the case statement here, instead of doing

```
"CDR_SOURCE_TYPE" = (your case statement)
```

do

```
(your case statement) as 'CDR_SOURCE_TYPE'
```

Comment: changed it like below CASE 
CDR_SOURCE_TYPE
WHEN CDR_SOURCE_TYPE IN ('SMSC') THEN DECODE(NETWORK_TYPE,'CDMA','SMSC_CDMA','HSPA','SMSC_HSPA')  still same